@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY) fields are populated with null value after parsing
Spring boot: 2.7.18
Groovy: 3.0.17
Gradle: gradle-8.6
Jackson: 2.13.5
Issue: Using JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY value is not working as expected after upgrading it from SB 1.5.x to SB 2.7.x. When we bind the response JSON with the DTO it is populating the properties with the READ_ONLY attribute as NULL.
Below is the code snippet for Service 1:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty

class WorkOrder {
    String id
    String batchId
    String orderId
    String manufacturingBatchType
    String manufacturingFamily

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    String dateCreated

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    String lastUpdated

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    String deviceFamilyName

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    String batchingId

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "WorkOrder{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", batchId='" + batchId + '\'' +
                ", orderId='" + orderId + '\'' +
                ", manufacturingBatchType='" + manufacturingBatchType + '\'' +
                ", manufacturingFamily='" + manufacturingFamily + '\'' +
                ", dateCreated='" + dateCreated + '\'' +
                ", lastUpdated='" + lastUpdated + '\'' +
                ", deviceFamilyName='" + deviceFamilyName + '\'' +
                ", batchingId='" + batchingId + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping('/v1/secure/workOrders')
class WorkOrderResource {

    @Autowired
    WorkOrderModule workOrderModule

    @RequestMapping(value = '{workOrderId}', method = GET, produces = [APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    @Operation(summary = 'Get workOrder with workOrderId')
    @Counted(name = 'getWorkOrder', absolute = true)
    @PreAuthorize("!@securityCheck.isSecurityEnabled() or hasAnyRole('ROLE_APP')")
    WorkOrder getWorkOrder(@PathVariable Long workOrderId) {
        workOrderModule.findWorkOrder(workOrderId)
    }
}

Code Snippet for Service 2 which is making an API call to Service 1:
@Component
@Slf4j
class DeviceManagerSearchRequests {

    @Autowired
    WorkOrderApi workOrderApi


    WorkOrder requestWorkOrdersFromDeviceManager(Long id) {
        try {
            WorkOrder workOrder = workOrderApi.getWorkOrder(id)
            return workOrder
        } catch (e) {
            log.error('Exception occurred in requestWorkOrdersFromDeviceManager ' + e.message, e)
        }
    }
}

public interface WorkOrderApi {
    @GET("/v1/secure/workOrders/{id}")
    WorkOrder getWorkOrder(@Path("id") Long var1);
}

Response from Postman:
{
    "id" : "28847822" ,
    "batchId" : "EVT4Z6MVS-260-PKG" ,
    "orderId" : "202312261718001269089165" ,
    "manufacturingBatchType" : "MFG_BATCH" ,
    "manufacturingFamily" : "Sports wMFG Batch" ,
    "dateCreated" : "2024-05-02T14:08:34.698" ,
    "lastUpdated" : "2024-05-02T16:09:32.276" ,
    "deviceFamilyName" : "HP Equipment Router" ,
    "batchingId" : 10
}

Actual response from the API call workOrderApi.getWorkOrder(id):
WorkOrder{id='28847822', batchId='EVT4Z6MVS-260-PKG', orderId='202312261718001269089165', manufacturingBatchType='MFG_BATCH', manufacturingFamily='Sports wMFG Batch', dateCreated='null', lastUpdated='null', deviceFamilyName='null', batchingId='null'}
Expected response from the API call workOrderApi.getWorkOrder(id):
WorkOrder{id='28847822', batchId='EVT4Z6MVS-260-PKG', orderId='202312261718001269089165', manufacturingBatchType='MFG_BATCH', manufacturingFamily='Sports wMFG Batch', dateCreated='2024-05-02T14:08:34.698', lastUpdated='2024-05-02T16:09:32.276', deviceFamilyName='HP Equipment Router', batchingId='10'}
If you observe the expected o/p. Here the fields are populated with the actual values not with the null values.
NOTE: It is populating the value if we remove the READ_ONLY code:
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
But it is required as we do not want these fields to be write by the client.

This was a bug in the older version of Jackson 2.11 but it was supposed to be fixed in 2.12. I am not sure whether it has been fixed or not.
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2779

Your properties are marked JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY, so only usable for Json serialization.
Jackson javadoc:

Access setting that means that the property may only be read for serialization (value accessed via "getter" Method, or read from Field) but not written (set) during deserialization. Put another way, this would reflect "read-only POJO", in which value contained may be read but not written/set.

In your test you shared above, you are doing deserialization (from JSON to POJO) with the method readValue so the behaviour is expected. As Jackson javadoc says, it may be confusing:

Various options for access property, specifying how property may be accessed during serialization ("read") and deserialization ("write") (note that the direction of read and write is from perspective of the property, not from external data format: this may be confusing in some contexts).

You should use JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY if you want your properties to be only available for deserialization.

Yes you are correct. For the simplicity I have asked the query by giving the above example.
I have updated the description with the exact scenario. Please refer to that.

Yes you are correct. For the simplicity I have asked the query by giving the above example.
The correct scenario is we are making an API call from one service to other as below:
WorkOrder workOrder = workOrderApi.searchWorkOrders(workOrderSearchRequest)
But in this case the Read_Only properties of the WorkOrder is populated with null whereas in the Postman API call response they are populated with the correct value.
